/wp pages showing in Google Analytics
Suddenly if I go to Engagement in GA4 and look at the pages being viewed, I am getting all kinds of backend files. I have scanned with Wordfence and everything is good. I have never had this in any account before. Does anyone know why this would suddenly be happening?
Most of the pages aren't even valid - they just go to a 404

